# JavaScript +css - Change main category's checkbox css, if any items beneath it are checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

All,

I have the attached code snippet where a category checkbox is checked if all items underneath it are checked. How can I modify the code such that:

1. If any checkbox underneath any category is checked, the CSS Style of it's parent "Category" checkbox should look greyed out. (I do not want to disable the checkbox. Just look grey or any color through CSS). This will denote some items are checked if the category is collapsed.
2. If all items are checked underneath a category, then the checkbox doesn't have to look greyed out as it will be checked too.

All the existing code functionality should be maintained as it works great..

PS: Sorry for the HTML being a mess...

Any suggestions? 
Thanks

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

<script>
google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");
google.load("jqueryui", "1.7.2");
</script>

<script language="JavaScript">
function toggleTableRows()
{
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('img.parent')
      .css("cursor","pointer")
      .toggle(
        function() {
          $(this).attr("title","Click to Expand")
          $(this).attr("src","arrow_collapsed.gif");
          $('tr').siblings('#child-'+this.id).toggle();
        },
        function() {
          $(this).attr("title","Click to Collapse");
          $(this).attr("src","arrow_expanded.gif");
          $('tr').siblings('#child-'+this.id).toggle();
        }
      ); 
    initCheckBoxes();
  });
} 
function toggleCheckboxes(current, form, field) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#"+ form +" :checkbox[name^='"+ field +"[']")
      .attr("checked", current.checked);
  });
} 
function toggleParentCheckboxes(current, form) {        
  var checked = $("#"+ form +" :checkbox[name='"+ current.name +"']").length == 
                $("#"+ form +" :checkbox[name='"+ current.name +"']:checked").length;
  // replace '[anything]' with '' instead of just '[]'
  $("#"+ form +" :checkbox[name='"+ current.name.replace(/\[[^\]]*\]/, "") +"']")
    .attr("checked", checked);
} 
function initCheckBoxes(form) {
  $("#"+ form +" :checkbox:checked").each(function() {
    if (this.name.match(/chk[0-9]\[.*\]/)) {
      toggleParentCheckboxes(this, form);
    }
  });
}
</script>
<script language="JavaScript">toggleTableRows();</script>
  <style type="text/css">tr.c1 {display: none;}</style>
</head>
<body>

<form name="frmDinnerMenu" id="frmDinnerMenu" method="POST" action="">
<table border=1>
<tr>
    <td><img class="parent" id="0" src="arrow_collapsed.gif" title="Click to Expand">Category - Fruits</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk0" onclick="toggleCheckboxes(this, 'frmDinnerMenu', 'chk0');"/></td>
</tr>
<tr class="c1" id="child-0">
    <td>Apple</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="true" name="chk0[]" onclick="toggleParentCheckboxes(this, 'frmDinnerMenu');"/></td>
</tr>
<tr class="c1" id="child-0">
    <td>Banana</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="false" name="chk0[]" onclick="toggleParentCheckboxes(this, 'frmDinnerMenu');"/></td>
</tr>
<tr class="c1" id="child-0">
    <td>Orange</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" checked value="true" name="chk0[]" onclick="toggleParentCheckboxes(this, 'frmDinnerMenu');"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><img class="parent" id="1" src="arrow_collapsed.gif" title="Click to Expand">Category - Vegetables</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk1" onclick="toggleCheckboxes(this, 'frmDinnerMenu', 'chk1');"/></td>
</tr>
<tr class="c1" id="child-1">
    <td>Eggplant</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="true" name="chk1[]" onclick="toggleParentCheckboxes(this, 'frmDinnerMenu');"/></td>
</tr>
<tr class="c1" id="child-1">
    <td>Tomato</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="false" name="chk1[]" onclick="toggleParentCheckboxes(this, 'frmDinnerMenu');"/></td>
</tr>
<tr class="c1" id="child-1">
    <td>Cabbage</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" checked value="true" name="chk1[]" onclick="toggleParentCheckboxes(this, 'frmDinnerMenu');"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code looks familiar ;)

Include a CSS class similar to this one (add further styling if you need it)

```
.graymeout { background-color:#D8D8D8 }
```

Change `toggleParentCheckboxes` to this (some "optimizations" included. Refactored out common selector parts and removed a "double" selection by using filter)

```
function toggleParentCheckboxes(current, form) {
    var selector1 = "#"+ form +" :checkbox[name='";
    var selector2 = selector1 + current.name +"']";
    var set = $(selector2);
    var checked = set.length == set.filter(":checked").length;
    // replace '[anything]' with '' instead of just '[]'
    var ele = $(selector1 + current.name.replace(/\[[^\]]*\]/, "") +"']");
    ele.attr("checked", checked);
    if(!checked)
        ele.addClass("graymeout")
    else
        ele.removeClass("graymeout");
    ele=null; set=null; selector1=null; selector2=null;
}
```

If you change the call to `initCheckBoxes` in `toggleTableRows` to `initCheckBoxes("frmDinnerMenu");` you will get the highlighting also on page load instead of just when first child is changed.

Answer (score 0):

I had also used the same approach as mentioned by jitter. It works pretty well and in my opinion is the only option available since a tri-state check box is not available on a browser.